# try/catch/finally Exception with System.exit(0)

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

```
try {
    fruit fr = (fruit) p;
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("not the right object");
} finally {
    System.out.println("finablock");
}
```

why in this case `System.exit(0)` didn't terminate the action and I got the two displays from the `catch` and the `finally` blocks?

Answer (score 2):

If an `Exception` is thrown, the execution immediately returns from the surrounding block, (re)-throwing said `Exception`. If a matching `catch`-block is found during traversing up the call stack, this `catch`-block is executed, from here on, execution resumes normally. All `finally`-blocks on the way up the call stacks are executed, in the order they are encountered.

For the example, this means that if

```
fruit fr = (fruit) p;
```

throws an `Exception`, then `System.exit(0);` is not executed, but the execution continues with the body of the `catch (Exception e)`-block. And due to the semantics of `finally`, this block is executed just before the method returns.

---

Some remarks on the code:

- Class names in java should be written in `UpperCamelCase` (`fruit fr = ...` -> `Fruit fr = ...`)
- If we want to terminate the application abnormally through `System.exit(...)`, then we should set a value `!= 0` since this is the exit code of the program. A value of `0` signals that the application terminated normally (which is most likely not true)